# Конструкции "так как... то", "поскольку... то"

Tags: грамотная-речь, союзы

Можно ли использовать конструкции "так как... то", "поскольку... то" (по аналогии со сложносоставным союзом "если... то"), или в сочетании с "так как" и "поскольку" использование "то" неверно?

Answer (score 5):

Можно-можно!

*Так как они сеяли ветер, то и пожнут бурю: хлеба на корню не будет у него; зерно не даст муки; а если и даст, то чужие проглотят ее.*

**[источник](http://www.mepar.ru/library/bible/vethy_zavet/prorok/hos/8/)**

*Поскольку все согласны, то (так) и я не возражаю.*

**[источник](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/175026)**

---

[Замечание Л. Поливанова:](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/wordhistory/648/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA)

> «Союз *так как* (удобство которого в том, что сопровождаемое им
>   придаточное предложение может стоять и перед главным) весьма редко
>   употребляется образцовыми писателями, как неблагозвучный. Вместо него
>   (всегда после другого союза) они обыкновенно ставят *как:* ”... а как
>   сам Сократ ничего не писал, то... мы должны полагаться на Ксенофонта и
>   Платона“; ”Жаловались на то, что немцы живут в их приходах..., но как
>   государь уважал иностранцев, то сии жалобы не имели успеха“; ”Петр
>   Великий запретил коленопреклонение, а как народ того не слушал, то
>   Петр Великий запретил уже сие под жестоким наказанием“»; «Таких...
>   пыжей можно положить в один карман более сотни, но как у многих
>   деревенских охотников нет... материала для вырубки пыжей, то они
>   употребляют...»

Answer (score 3):

В "Синтаксисе современного русского языка"  говорится, что "союзы ТАК КАК, ПОСКОЛЬКУ, РАЗ **могут образовывать двойные (двухместные) союзные соединения** с постпозитивными частицами ТО и ТАК и словами со значением умозаключения ЗНАЧИТ, СЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНО, СТАЛО БЫТЬ".